# why Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'require' error is giving?

Tags: angularjs

I tried many solutions from here but still its showing this error

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'require'. Consider
>   exporting the symbol (position 8:13 in the original .ts file),
>   resolving symbol AppModule in
>   C:/Users/Bristy/Documents/realtime_chart/client/src/app/app.module.ts
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! live-chart@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the live-chart@0.0.0 build script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Bristy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-05-09T17_11_42_862Z-debug.log
>   Done.

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts/index';

import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';

declare var require: any;



 export function highchartsFactory() {

      const hc = require('highcharts');

      const dd = require('highcharts/modules/drilldown');

      dd(hc);


      return hc;

    }


@NgModule({

  declarations: [

    AppComponent

  ],

  imports: [

    BrowserModule,

    FormsModule,

    HttpModule,

    ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts/highstock')),

  ],

  providers: [ {

          provide: HighchartsStatic,

          useFactory: highchartsFactory

        }],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';

declare var require: any;

export function highchartsFactory() {
  const hc = require('highcharts/highstock');
  const dd = require('highcharts/modules/exporting');
  dd(hc);
  return hc;
  }
  
  

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts/highstock')),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HighchartsStatic,
      useFactory: highchartsFactory
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```